# Window displays not correctly

Tags: java, javafx

I have a simple application on JavaFx, just button and TextField in VBox. When I start it, the window displays a blank space at the right side. How I can fix this?

```
public class FxTest extends Application {

    Stage window;
    Scene scene1;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        window = stage;
        TextField tf = new TextField();
        Button b = new Button("click");
        b.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println(tf.getText()));

        VBox layout = new VBox();
        layout.getChildren().addAll(tf, b);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(20));

        scene1 = new Scene(layout, 200, 300);

        window.setScene(scene1);
        window.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: When I run your code - it works just fine.  What version of Java are you running?  OS?

Comment: I use java 9.0.1 and Windows Home on my laptop. I just reinstalled Java and IDE but the problem has not dissapeared. This happens when i run any code even sample code in Idea or NetBeans.

Comment: Not sure what is going on then, I ran on Java 9 with a NetBeans dev build and it works for me.  I even resized, and didn't see the behavior you are experiencing.